# HP ML350 G6 No POST, All Lights Green, previosuly working with ILO2 connection

Tags: windows, hardware, hp-proliant, boot

Greetings and salutations

I have a working previously working server which I’ve used for 7 months with no downtime other than updates and OS upgrade, now I purchased another server and removed all the RAM and CPU from this server on to the new one.

I updated from the original 4 core to 6 core and updated the ram from 8 to 32GB and all was fine no issues and I removed all this components and put them into the newly purchased server and purchased a new 1 x6 core CPU and 1x 8GB stick of RAM for that original server I since removed all the parts for.

I put them in the original server now not posting, and this is where the fun begins.

Current Server State:

I can power on the server and all the lights are green e.g. the front two and on the motherboard. There are not beeps or error sounds what so ever it turns on and I can get to ILO2 and the NIC cards are Green so no obvious signs or any issues.

X4 CPU FANS
X1 6 core CPU (new purchased)
X1 8 GB of RAM (new purchased)
Full HDD with OS but cannot reach as not POST
X1 PSU 750 Watts
PS3 Keyboard with Num lock turn on

Tried Solutions: 
assuming I’ve turn off server before changing jumper or removing components and server has been turn on and on again.

(1) Installed CPU and Ram and turn on without changing (no post) just jet fan noise

(2) Changed jumper setting to turn off 1,2,5,6, off turn on server for 3 mins turn then turn on server (no post)

(3) Changed jumper to 6 only (no post) just get noise

(4) Changed jumper to 5.6 only (no post) just get engine noise

(5) Removed CMOS batter and changed jumper 6 also 5,6 also 1,2,5,6 (no post)

(6) Remove RAM turn on server and no missing ram error as no post so cannot see ram

I can reach ILO2 and login however it shows nothing as it cannot see anything e.g. cpu, ram, etc

I’m at a loss as I though that removing the RAM module would produce an error message but to no avail however it was working and the OS and RAID haven’t been touched so it basically I just remove components and replaced them.

Comment: Did you update all the system firmware before installing the new CPU? If not, put the old CPU back in and do that.

Comment: thanks for the update however i did specify the CPU was a 4 core originally which i change to a 6 core and it was fine and working. Then i purchased a new 6 core (same spec) and its not working so i don't thinks is the CPU as i have used both 6 and 4 core. also i cannot put the original CPU back in as i specified i used it in another server which is full operational and severing clients. thanks for the suggestion